# Symfony 5 and customer github package

Tags: php, composer-php

I am learning how to create my first composer package.
To achieve that, I created the following public repository on my GH: https://github.com/Alphabetus/alpha-logger.

I managed to successfully install my package on a project but when i try to call the class from the package i get the following error:
[image: Output Error]

The package code is public as mentioned, am i assigning the namespace wrong?
On the test project I have the following:

- composer.json:

```
[...]
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/Alphabetus/alpha-logger"
        }
    ],
[...]
"require": {
    [...]
    "alphabetus/alpha-logger": "dev-master"
}
[...]
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

The `composer update` command goes OK and i can see my own package on `vendor/alphabetus/AlphaLogger`

On my controller Im trying to call my logger class like this:

- PageController.php

```
use AlphaLogger\Logger as Logger;
[...]

public function index(... ...)
{
    $l = new Logger();
    $l->test();
}
```

Comment: Have you defined an `autoload` section in your packae's `composer.json`?

Comment: @yivi added the autoload config, pretty much standard symfony

Comment: @yivi for my project

Comment: You'll need to create the section in your **package**, so the autoloader is correctly created in your project (or whatever project that requires your package)

Comment: @yivi yes!! the autoloader was the problem. I was setting it wrong on my package repo.